# formset function update view does not save the forms because the id is missing

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view to update 6 of my formset only that the click of the send button gives me the error that the id of each form is missing ... how do you fix it?

When I have to create formset there are never problems with the id...
Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? I leave my code below

view

```
@login_required
def PianoSingleUpdateView(request, id):
    piano = models.Piano.objects.get(single_piano__id = id)
    piano_sett = models.PianoSingleDay.objects.get(id = id)
    dato = models.PianoDay.objects.filter( piano_day = piano_sett)

    DatiFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.PianoDay, extra = 0, fields=('id', 'kcal', 'carboidrati', 'proteine', 'grassi'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dati_formset = DatiFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset = dato)

        if dati_formset.is_valid():
            for dato in dati_formset:
                dato.save()

            return redirect('gestione-piano', id = piano.id)
    else:
        dati_formset = DatiFormSet(queryset = dato)

    context = {'piano': piano, 'piano_sett': piano_sett, 'dati_formset': dati_formset}
    return render(request, 'crud/update/update_piano_giornaliero.html', context)
```

models

```
class Piano(models.Model):
  nome_piano = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  data_inizio = models.DateField()
  data_fine = models.DateField()
  utente_piano = models.ForeignKey(
    User, 
    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    related_name = 'utente_piano'
  )
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.nome_piano
  

class PianoSingleDay(models.Model):
    giorni_settimana_scelta = [
        ("1","Lunedì"),
        ("2","Martedì"),
        ("3","Mercoledì"),
        ("4","Giovedì"),
        ("5","Venerdì"),
        ("6","Sabato"),
        ("7","Domenica")
    ]
    giorni_settimana = models.CharField(
        choices = giorni_settimana_scelta,
        max_length = 300
    )
    single_piano = models.ForeignKey(
        Piano,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = 'single_piano'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.giorni_settimana


class PianoDay(models.Model):
    scelta_pasto = [
        ("1","Colazione"),
        ("2","Spuntino mattina"),
        ("3","Pranzo"),
        ("4","Merenda"),
        ("5","Cena"),
        ("6","Spuntino sera")
    ]
    pasto = models.CharField(
        choices = scelta_pasto,
        max_length = 300,
        default = '-'
    )
    kcal = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    grassi = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    carboidrati = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    proteine = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    piano_day = models.ForeignKey(
        PianoSingleDay,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = 'piano_day'
    )
```

file html

```
<form method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off" class="form-not-box">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="box-schede">
        <div class="alert alert-pop-up mt-3" role="alert">
            Le colonne lasciate a 0 non verranno considerate.
        </div>

        {{ dati_formset.management_form }}

        <div class="row mt-3">
            {% for dati in dati_formset %}
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="info-piano">
                        <div class="ico">
                            {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static 'img/icone/colazione.svg' %}">
                                    Icona colazione
                                </object>
                            {% elif forloop.counter == 3 %}
                                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static 'img/icone/pranzo.svg' %}">
                                    Icona pranzo
                                </object>
                            {% elif forloop.counter == 5 %}
                                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static 'img/icone/cena.svg' %}">
                                    Icona cena
                                </object>
                            {% elif forloop.counter == 2 or forloop.counter == 4 or forloop.counter == 6 %}
                                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static 'img/icone/merenda.svg' %}">
                                    Icona cena
                                </object>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                            {{ dati.kcal|add_class:'form-control'|append_attr:"placeholder: dati" }}
                            {{ dati.kcal.label_tag }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            {{ dati.carboidrati|add_class:'form-control'|append_attr:"placeholder: dati" }}
                            {{ dati.carboidrati.label_tag }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            {{ dati.proteine|add_class:'form-control'|append_attr:"placeholder: dati" }}
                            {{ dati.proteine.label_tag }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            {{ dati.grassi|add_class:'form-control'|append_attr:"placeholder: dati" }}
                            {{ dati.grassi.label_tag }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons mb-3">
        <a href="{% url 'gestione-piano' piano.id %}" class="btn btn-warning-rev">Indietro</a>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Aggiorna piano">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I suggest you remove the id field in DatiFormSet. fields=('kcal', 'carboidrati', 'proteine', 'grassi'))

Answer (score 0):

My observation tells me that your problem is the DatiFormSet fields which shouldn't contain id value and also your function view had in queryset = dato which is not needed, but in some cases you should add an instance of Piano.

```
@login_required
def PianoSingleUpdateView(request, id):
    piano = models.Piano.objects.get(single_piano__id = id)
    piano_sett = models.PianoSingleDay.objects.get(id = id)
    dato = models.PianoDay.objects.filter( piano_day = piano_sett)

    DatiFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.PianoDay, extra = 0, fields=('kcal', 'carboidrati', 'proteine', 'grassi'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dati_formset = DatiFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES , instance=piano)

        if dati_formset.is_valid():
            for dato in dati_formset:
                dato.save()
                return redirect('gestione-piano', id = piano.id)
    else:
        dati_formset = DatiFormSet(request.POST)

    context = {'piano': piano, 'piano_sett': piano_sett, 'dati_formset': dati_formset}
    return render(request, 'crud/update/update_piano_giornaliero.html', context)
```